# Entity Framework Upsert async race condition. Is there a better workaround?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

A Post against my MVC5 WebAPI controller checks to see if an item exists in the database and then adds it if it does not exist. If it does exists, it updates it. It does not use the primary key, identity field, but by field called Name.

The scenario is like this.
I have two JSON clients trying to add (Post) a record. 
The application is taking some time to warmup.
Once the application is up, the first Post hits and its first async query checks for existence.
While that is in await, the second Post hits and checks for existence, finds no record, then inserts it.
Then the first Post returns from its await, has found no record and inserts it.

So first I put a unique index on the Name field so it would error on the above condition.
Then my first Post would error for duplicate index violation, which is good.
Then I changed my EF calls to not be async, thinking I would not relinquish (via await) to the second Post and my first Post would just forge ahead executing the read then insert. This seems to allow both Posts to complete without any duplicate insert error. Note: the second post now does an update and not an insert.

I assume this does not eliminate the possibility of the index violation error in a multithreading environment.
Perhaps a C# lock would work, but not scale to multiple servers.
From other SO threads, I read that EF Upserts (AddOrUpdate) are not thread safe, e.g. not true SQL Upserts.

Probably many unsuspecting programmers have these kinds of bugs, who, like me, just started slapping async/await around everything.

Is there a more robust workaround (without a stored procedure)?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with asynchrony. The exact same problem happens for synchronous code, since WebApi is an inherently multithreaded scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to fix this.

1. Stop the second call to the database

Place the check if exists and the insert inside a transaction. Then the second call would wait until the first completed, and it would see that the data is already in the database.

2. Let the second update occur

If it does not create any problems, let the second update occur.

If this problem happens 1 in 1000 calls, then it may be better with one extra database update rather than 1000 database locks.